# Restore container after docker-destkop uninstall on Windows

Tags: docker

I met some issues with docker-desktop on Windows and performed a fresh install.
The only problem is that my images and containers are gone...

I'm only interested to recover one specific container using TensorFlow, containing jupyter notebook that I should have save.

Is there any way to restore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry but you won't be able to restore it.

- When you have Docker Desktop without WSL2 backend, the resources are stored under `C:\ProgramData\docker` and those are deleted at uninstall.
- When you have Docker Desktop with WSL2 backend, the distribution where Docker is running is completely wiped out at uninstall.

---

I suppose you were using the official image under `tensorflow/tensorflow` (or the equivalent with GPU support), so next time don't forget to use a `volume` for those contents you'd like to persist or even better, have a disposable container that binds-mount your workspace.

Example:

1. Create a folder under `C:` where you want your Jupyter Workspace, let's say `C:\Projects`
2. Start the container by mounting that folder on the container and run Jupyter Notebook: `docker run -it --rm -v C:\Projects:/usr/workspace -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-jupyter`
3. When you access to your Notebook in the browser (under `localhost:8888`), open in Jupyter Notebook the directory `/usr/workspace`, so all the work you're doing will be also stored in the host in `C:\Projects`
4. When you finish, you can safely stop and delete your container, since the work is stored in the host and not only in the container.

Comment: Yes,... I knew it, I just wanted to be sure. My bad, I thought it will be some kind of warning during uninstall if they were deleting it (maybe it was?) Anyway, thank you a lot for your answer !